# How to sort List with Comparator to sort null value properly?

Tags: java, spring, sorting, arraylist

What I trying to achieve is sorting a list with two conditions, I want to sort based List that inside my object and when it's `null` I want it sorted at last.

Here is what I do, here is my UnAssignedSoResponse.java object :

```
public class UnAssignedSoResponse {

    public Double cbm;

    public ShipmentAddressGroupingResponseHdOnlyDto shipmentAddressGroupingResponseHdOnlyDto;

}
```

and here is how my code in the service look like :

```
List<UnAssignedSoResponse> unAssignedSoResponse = ObjectMapperUtils.mapAll(salesOrders, UnAssignedSoResponse.class);

    unAssignedSoResponse.sort(Comparator.comparing(u -> u.getShipmentAddressGroupingResponseHdOnlyDto().getShipmentGroupName()),Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

above my variable `unAssignedSoResponse` is a list, and I want it to sort based list that named `shipmentAddressGroupingResponseHdOnlyDto`, sometimes `shipmentAddressGroupingResponseHdOnlyDto` is `null`, I want to set null at the last of the list. but I got an error in "sort" underlined red if I write something like above, the error is :

```
The method sort(Comparator<? super UnAssignedSoResponse>) in the type List<UnAssignedSoResponse> is not applicable for the arguments (Comparator<UnAssignedSoResponse>, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
```

if i want to sort based the shipmentGroupName, i can do something like this :

```
        unAssignedSoResponse.sort(Comparator.comparing(u -> u.getShipmentAddressGroupingResponseHdOnlyDto().getShipmentGroupName()));
```

How do I sort `null` safe over there?

UPDATE :

i update my code as Louis Wasserman answer to something like this :

```
    unAssignedSoResponse.sort(
        Comparator.nullsLast(
            Comparator.comparing(
                u -> u.getShipmentAddressGroupingResponseHdOnlyDto(),
                Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(d -> d.getShipmentGroupName()))
            )
        )
    );
```

there is no error, but my list won't sorted the null at last ArrayList and it won't sort at all, what did i missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unAssignedSoResponse.sort(
   Comparator.nullsLast(
      Comparator.comparing(
        u -> u.getShipmentAddressGroupingResponseHdOnlyDto(),
        Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(d -> d.getShipmentGroupName())));
```

All you need is to use [`nullsLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast-java.util.Comparator-).

Comment: the error in underlined in sort property is gone, but i still got error NullPointerException@157 "java.lang.NullPointerException" when sorting the data

Comment: @KeVin Updated the code based on a better understanding of the input.

Comment: yes, first thank you sir, but in your code seems miss two close bracket and when i add two more it show no more error, but when i run the code, it still not sort my list, when shipmentAddressGroupingResponseHdOnlyDto value null one is still on the top

Comment: i am sorry, there is nothing wrong with the code, i just put the code at wrong line, that's my list doesn't sort. Thank u mr